# Using AngularFire with angular 2.0 alpha

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I was trying to look this up online, but didn't find any useful resources. Essentially I am using ionic v2 to build an app and would like to use firebase backend, therefore I wanted to know if there is a guide on how to set it up in with angular 2.0, its not a production app, just a small project to test out new releases.

Comment: I don't see anyway you can do that for now. Because angularfire is based on angularJS and not angular 2 so, it would be very surprising if it works and even if you trick a bit to make it work, you surely wont get a 3 way data binding.

Comment: See [Sara's talk on Firebase and Angular2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RD0xYicNcaY); you don't really need a lib to make this work.

Comment: @Kato thats really useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out we don't need to rely on AngularFire when using angular 2 with firebase, Thank you @Kato for pointing it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RD0xYicNcaY